# How do I use Javascript API in non-Javascript project?

Tags: c#, javascript

I am working on a C# project which requires some map task.

What I am doing is writing a html file in C# and display it with a webview-like component.

And this is awkward.

Somebody came up with a more reasonable way? This can be a general problem since there are so many Javascript API.

Comment: Do you need to display a map, or just lookup some information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have a Javascript engine running within your C program in order to interpret and execute Javascript code.  This can be done though it's seldom without issue since a lot of Javascript code assumes the existence of a browser (e.g. calling `window.location` or methods that add DOM elements).

This is *definitely* going to be more trouble than it's worth for your particular case - as well as being orders of magnitude less efficient than just writing the algorithm in C#.  You should be looking for a C# library that simplifies the creation of HTML, rather than trying to embed an interpreted, weakly-typed language.

(However it can be a valid approach for other situations where you have important business logic in Javascript, and need to replicate this in a performance-insensitive batch process.  Or if you want to run automated tests on your JS code alongside C#/Java classes.)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it though would be to run a node js server and simply talk over local ports. I am sure you would have no trouble talking over http with c# and it will no doubt be much cleaner then the way you are doing it now.

Also you can include the v8 engine straight into you current project. It is just a javascript interpreter in C that builds as your usual library header deal ( I can not say how hard this is I have no C# experience ).